# $\lim_{k \to \infty}(U(P_k,f)-L(P_k,f))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Q. Let $f:[a,b]\to R$ be a bounded function. Suppose there exists a sequence of partitions $\{P_k\}$ $$\lim_{k \to \infty}(U(P_k,f)-L(P_k,f))=0.$$
Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable and that $$\int_a^b f = \lim_{k \to \infty}U(P_k,f)=\lim_{k\to \infty}L(P_k,f).$$

Let $P_k=(a=x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_k=b)$ such that $x_i = \frac ik$ for $k \in N, i\le k.$

Let $\int_a^bf=I$. Then, we know that $L(P_k,f)\le I \le U(P_k,f).$ Thus, the sequence of $L(P_k,f)$ and $U(P_k,f)$ are bounded. I was trying to prove the question by using the monotone bounded sequence theorem. But, I realize that the sequence is not monotone increasing and decreasing, respectively in this partition. What should be an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

Start from $$L(f,P) \le \underline\int_a^b f \le \overline\int_a^b f \le U(f,P)$$ valid for every partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ .

Then $$ 0 \le \overline\int_a^b f - \underline\int_a^b f \le U(f,P) - L(f,P) $$**Edit**

In the same way you can get also $$0 \le U(f,P) - \overline\int_a^b f \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)$$ and $$0 \le \underline\int_a^b f - L(f,P) \le U(f,P) - L(f,P)$$

Comment: Using your hint, I can solve that $f$ is Riemann integrable, but I still can't do the second question. Could you give some help?

Comment: You can get other two inequalities in the same way. See my edit.